# improve image application performance

Tags: java, javax.imageio

I have a java se 6 application which receive between 10 and 15 BufferedImage.

The app has to write these BufferedImage in shared memory in order to a C program to read it and display the images.

The problem is the images are big, from 1900*1600 to 800 * 600 and the transformation in byte[] with ImageIO take a long time: 50ms for the biggest images. I need this byte[] to write in the memory and ImageIo is the fastest way i found.

If i have 4 large images, it take 50 * 4 = 200 ms to refresh an image  :(

Do you have any idea how i could improve it ? 
Should i care about 1 image in 1 thread ? I will have 15 threads and the cpu is already working around 60%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of writing the images using imageio. have you tried GetPixels().
the imageio writes the data to a specific codec like TIFF / MJPEG.
what you need its the actual data (the pixels).
now you need to write the C code to be able to render pixels.
(how are you planning to pass the data to the C code? pointers???).

Comment: unfortunately i had no more time to try it fully :(

With my last tests, it seems that, surprisingly given the benchmark below, getPixels has good answer time.

If people are trying to improve their process, they should try it, and maybe confirm it ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is feedback from benchmark i runned: 

resumse: it seems that ImageIO is the most optimized class for image processing.

Process : BufferedImage => byte[] => Byte[] => int[] => write
note: using ImageIO for convert image in byte[]

image 1900 * 1600
get a byte[] from BufferedImage: 45 ms
cast byte[] en Byte[] : 0 ms
write in memory: 4 à 9 ms

image 1280 * 1024
get a byte[] from BufferedImage: 20 à 23 ms
cast byte[] en Byte[] : 0 ms
write in memory: 4 à 7 ms

image 800 * 600
get a byte[] from BufferedImage: 9 ms
cast byte[] en Byte[] : 0 ms
write in memoire: 3 à 5 ms

==> linear processing, the best that we can get

Process : BufferedImage => int[] => write
note: use getRGB for convert image in int[]

image 1900 * 1600 : 2500 ms

==> getRGB get each image pixel: 3 millions that you have to write: too long

Process : BufferedImage => Raster => DataBuffer => write

get a DataBuffer from BufferedImage: 0 ms
write in memoire: 2500 ms

image 1900 * 1600 : 2500 ms

==> DataBuffer has a size of 3 millions, writing time too long